# Allow specific punctuation and remove aphostrophe

Tags: c#, regex, string, apostrophe, punctuation

I'm trying to remove specific punctuation from string

I need to keep in string only "`.`", "`,`", "`!`", "`+`", "`*`", "`-`" but remove everything, including  apostrophe "'"  for example

```
what's up!
```

must be:

```
whats up!
```

So this way, it removes everything

```
string res = Regex.Replace(filtr2, @"[^\w\s]", "");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope that you are looking for something like this :

```
string rexFormat=@"[^0-9a-zA-Z\.,!+\-* \w ]";
string myInPutString ="what'sup ! my dear friend?";
string replacedString = Regex.Replace(myInPutString, rexFormat, string.Empty);
// will give you whatsup ! my dear friend
```

The special characters `'` and `?` were removed